# Dynamically change CSS class

Tags: css

I want to require that a checkbox be checked on a Community form.  I am able to display an alert when it isn't checked.  I don't want to do that.  I want to display text on the form.  I think I should be able to do this by dynamically adding CSS.  I don't know how to do that.  Pointers?

```
    var legalChecked = component.find("legalnotice").get("v.value");
    if(!legalChecked) {
        alert("ugh!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use `$A.util.addClass(legalNotice, 'hasborder')` and `$A.util.removeClass(legalNotice, 'hasborder') to accomplish the dynamic application of CSS

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/125861)

Comment: Using addClass is the answer that I found to my problem.